# Cracking DES requires decrypting entire file?

Tags: security, encryption

I would like to know is it necessary to decrypt an entire DES-encrypted file to determine if the given key is correct.

If so, does it mean that the time taken in a brute force attack depends on file size? Are there any alternatives?

Also, does this apply to AES too?

I am asking this under the assumption that a bigger file takes a longer to time to decrypt/ encrypt. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, ciphers become *less* secure when there is more data to examine.

I'll give you an example: if you know you have thousands of encrypted blocks containing text, you might try and encrypt a known piece of text containing  characters. Now you have thousands of blocks to test against, if one matches, you've found the key. So if there is a connection with file size, its a reverse one: your key is more easily compromised if more data is available on the plain text. Of course, how much it helps depends on the data and the attack itself, on the mode of encryption used etc. etc..

Many implementations that are vulnerable to side channel attacks have even got a maximum number of times that a block may be encrypted/decrypted with a certain (session) key. After that a new key should be generated.

And to repeat the other answers, in many cases a single block is enough to perform a brute force attack on. Having more blocks only helps the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one plaintext-ciphertext pair is enough to make a brute-force attack. Such pairs can usually be retrieved by file headers if the file should have one.

Answer (score 1):

DES (or rather 3DES, as nobody uses DES anymore. Cracking DES requires...  a laptop and 50 minutes), as well as AES, are block ciphers. They do not *validate* the input, they simply apply the transformation and spit out the output. There no way to know if the file was correct or incorrect from a pure cryptographic point of view.

But all block cipher operate on one block at a time and you can you can have application specific headers at the beginning of your data which can be validated quickly (*short* magic numbers) and discard the entire data, w/o decrypting it, if they don't validate (long validation headers lend themselves to crib attacks, as blether points out). This by no means is the same as actually cryptographically validate the data, which is done by means of signatures and *does* require the entire data.

All in all, to keep a long story short: don't reinvent the wheel. Use of-the-shelf products like PGP. ["World is full of bad security systems designed by people who read Applied Cryptography."](http://www.schneier.com/book-sandl-pref.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to research the concept of "unicity distance".  In general, you only need to test that far into the file to be sure you have the correct key.  DES has a 64 bit key, 8 bytes.  For the majority of purposes, you probably won't need to decrypt more than the first two blocks, 16 bytes, before you can determine if the trial key is correct or not.

rossum

Comment: The effective DES key is 56 bits long. The other 8 bits are just there for error correction and irrelevant for cryptographical strength.